# Subquery returned more than 1 value. when the subquery is used as an expression.in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Here's my code

Subquery :

```
SELECT 
    A.StoreNo, C.[date], A.ProductBarCode, A.ProductQty
INTO 
    ##inv1
FROM  
    #calender C
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * 
     FROM ##Temp I 
     WHERE I.Date < C.DATE 
       AND StoreNo IN (SELECT StoreNo FROM ##StoreList)   
     ORDER BY I.Date) A
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

I used top 100 percent because I have more than 1000 productBarcode for each storeNo, if I choose top 1 its showing only one productBarcode duplicate value for next day.

```
Declare 
    @pheader nvarchar(Max), @sql_pivot nvarchar(max)

Begin 
    SELECT   
        @pheader = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([StoreNo])   
                          FROM ##StoreList
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')  
        --SET @pheader = LEFT(@pheader, LEN(@pheader) - 1)
                                                                                        SET @sql_pivot = 'SELECT *   
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT 
                                   S.[StoreNo], p.Date as Date, 
                                   p.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,
                                   ISNULL(i.productqty - (SELECT ProductQty as runningsum 
                                                          FROM #Stock st 
                                                          WHERE st.date <= i.date 
                                                            AND st.storeno = i.storeno 
                                                            AND st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode), i.productqty) as ProductQty

                                FROM #inventory i
                                LEFT JOIN ##StoreList S ON S.StoreNo = i.StoreNo
                                LEFT JOIN #Stock st ON st.StoreNo = i.StoreNo AND st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode AND st.Date = i.Date
                                RIGHT JOIN ##product p ON i.Date = P.Date and p.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode
                                -- where p.ProductBarCode IN(2300007115072,2300012213046,2300012712075)
                                GROUP BY S.storeNo, i.StoreNo, i.ProductBarCode, i.Date, p.ProductBarCode, p.Date, i.ProductQty) p

                          PIVOT (SUM(ProductQty) 
                                 FOR [StoreNo] IN ('+ @pheader+') )Pvt'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql_pivot
```

I cant get three to four storeNo at a time if i select more then 10 its showing this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I'm using SQL Server .

Comment: The error message explains the problem pretty clearly. You have a subquery that's returning more than one value. So where do you have a subselect? I only see one, which tells you precisely where the issue is happening. So extract that part, and figure out what is returning more than one row for that query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add top 1 to your subquery. try like this,

```
DECLARE @pheader NVARCHAR(Max)
    ,@sql_pivot NVARCHAR(max)

BEGIN
    SELECT @pheader = STUFF((
                SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([StoreNo])
                FROM ##StoreList
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @pheader = LEFT(@pheader, LEN(@pheader) - 1)
    SET @sql_pivot = 
        'SELECT *   
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT 
                                   S.[StoreNo], p.Date as Date, 
                                   p.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode,
                                   ISNULL(i.productqty - (SELECT top 1 ProductQty as runningsum 
                                                          FROM #Stock st 
                                                          WHERE st.date <= i.date 
                                                            AND st.storeno = i.storeno 
                                                            AND st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode), i.productqty) as ProductQty

                                FROM #inventory i
                                LEFT JOIN ##StoreList S ON S.StoreNo = i.StoreNo
                                LEFT JOIN #Stock st ON st.StoreNo = i.StoreNo AND st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode AND st.Date = i.Date
                                RIGHT JOIN ##product p ON i.Date = P.Date and p.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode
                                -- where p.ProductBarCode IN(2300007115072,2300012213046,2300012712075)
                                GROUP BY S.storeNo, i.StoreNo, i.ProductBarCode, i.Date, p.ProductBarCode, p.Date, i.ProductQty) p

                          PIVOT (SUM(ProductQty) 
                                 FOR [StoreNo] IN (' 
        + @pheader + ') )Pvt'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_pivot
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to order the query by date, address, or whatever that doesn't REPEAT. Souns like a very very dumb solution but it worked for me in an Access database with DESC counts.

Looks like if in orders the values repeat the sql returns more than needed... i really don't know why but it worked for me!

Try it!